# Has python a is_Prime() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I want to find out if a number a prime number.
This can I do with this code:

```
def is_prime(a):
    return all(a % i for i in range(2, a))
```

My question is whether python provides a function that checks if a number a prime number.

Comment: If your numbers are large, you can use [sympy's isprime](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.primetest.isprime)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, it does not have a builtin function, but you can do better with your code. First, you can improve the range to be from `(2, sqrt(a) + 1)` it will reduce the number of elements you check by a lot.